# Is it possible to add Facebook login/signup without using extensions?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, facebook

Is it possible to add Facebook login/signup without using extensions? If yes, how to do? Or does anyone here know a FREE extension for that?

Answer (score 5):

Of course it is possible without using extensions if you implement it yourself. But this is normally not reasonable. You will have to invest much more time implementing it yourself. It is usually cheaper to buy an existing extension. Existing/published extensions are also much more tested, because many people use them.

There are even free alternatives, yeah. Have a look at the ones from [BelVG](http://facebook-free.belvg.com/), from [VelanApps](http://store.velanapps.com/products/magento/free-facebook-login-extension) and especially the one from [Inchoo](https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_SocialConnect) (because it is on GitHub). There is also a [blog post](http://inchoo.net/magento/social-connect-magento-extension/) explaining the Inchoo extension.

If you want to implement it yourself anyway, the code of these free extensions may be a good starting point.